# Java CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY usage for imwrite in opencv 2.4.8

Tags: java, opencv, arraylist

I'm trying to set the compression level for a image I'm writing in Opencv 2.4.8 (Can't use a later version for now) in Java 1.8x using the following code:

```java
   ArrayList<Integer> parameters;
   parameters = new ArrayList;

   parameters.add(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
   parameters.add(quality);

   Highgui.imwrite("temp.jpg", image_entry, parameters);
```

On Compilation I'm currently getting:

```
 "error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to MatOfInt
        Highgui.imwrite("temp.jpg", image_entry, parameters);"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the `fromList( )` function. http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/MatOfInt.html

Comment: Yup did the trick thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: MatOfInt par = new MatOfInt();
par.fromList(parameters);